# Video not ready for use in an ad via Facebook Marketing API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

When I use the api to create an ad creative after uploading the video, an error happens: `The video is still being processed. Please wait for the video to finish processing before using it in an ad`.

My solution now is to sleep some time to wait until the video is ready.

So how long will it often take for the video to finish processing? Have some better way to handle this case?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a video for Instagram Ad. 1st upload it on Facebook. This way you can get rid of this error.

It helped me, I hope it works for you as well.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).